# awk command of add column to sum of repeated column

Tags: awk

i have a data set tab separated like this:

```
A  B  C  D
1  aaa 1 2
1  aaa 3 4
1  aaa 5 6
1  bbb 7 8
1  ccc 9 1
1  ccc 2 3
1  ddd 4 5
1  ddd 6 7
1  ddd 8 9
1  ddd 1 2
```

I want to add a new E column to show sum of C of groupped B

Desired output:

```
A  B  C  D E
1  aaa 1 2 9
1  aaa 3 4 9
1  aaa 5 6 9
1  ddd 4 5 19
1  ddd 6 7 19
1  ddd 8 9 19
1  ddd 1 2 19
```

Comment: Why are the lines comprising bb or cc missing from the output? Your title states, sum computation to be done on repeating column. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }
  NR==FNR{ 
    if (FNR>1) a[$2]+=$3
    next
  }
  { $(NF+1)=(FNR==1 ? "E" : a[$2]) }
  1
' file file
```

Read the input file twice. In the first run, skip the header line (`if (FNR>1)...`) and add the value of field `$3` to the value of array `a` with key `$2`.
Continue with the `next` record.

In the second run, assign `E` to new field `$(NF+1)` for the first line or the value of `a[$2]` for the other lines. Print the record.

Output:

```
A       B       C       D       E
1       aaa     1       2       9
1       aaa     3       4       9
1       aaa     5       6       9
1       bbb     7       8       7
1       ccc     9       1       11
1       ccc     2       3       11
1       ddd     4       5       19
1       ddd     6       7       19
1       ddd     8       9       19
1       ddd     1       2       19
```

Comment: it's worked. How can i edit, if i want to didnt use head in input?

Comment: Change `if (FNR>1) a[$2]+=$3` to `a[$2]+=$3` and the line with the assignment to `{ $(NF+1)=a[$2] }` if there is no header.

Comment: its worked again, thanks @Freddy